# Override OnPaint

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, windows-forms-designer

If I override OnPaint and draw a square on the control, how do I get that e.graphics.draw... to show up when I'm previewing it in the designer?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a focus rectangle on a custom drawn control, or how to see the results of an overriden OnPaint when looking at a control's designer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164145.aspx

> While you could manually register with
>   Control.OnPaint to add your design
>   time UI, you'll find that overriding
>   OnPaintAdornments is a better option
>   because it is only called after the
>   control's design-time/run-time UI is
>   painted, letting you put the icing on
>   the cake (see Figure 20). Simply
>   adding DesignerAttribute to the
>   ClockControl class completes the
>   association: Copy Code
>
> [
>   Designer(typeof(ClockControlDesigner))
>   ] class ClockControl : Control { ... }

Comment: It's good that you included the paragraph description, because those links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to draw a focus rectangle for you control, and have it be visible when manipulating your control after it has been added to a form, then [Gaijin42's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738694/override-onpaint/738700#738700) should work.

If you're trying to see what your custom drawn control looks like...

- If you've overriden the `OnPaint` method in the control, you should see the results of that `OnPaint` when you look at your control after it has been added to a form (or another control).
- If you're trying to see the results of the `Paint` when looking at the designer for the control itself, [I don't think that is possible](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-controls/4329/UserControl-Painting-in-Control-Designer) (at least it wasn't with VS2005):

  > Unfortunately this is not possible.
  >   While you're writing the behaviours 
  >   of the user control the code isn't
  >   compiled and the designer actually 
  >   uses an ordinary user control to host
  >   the child controls. The `OnPaint`
  >   override etc will not run.
  >
  > To debug the overrides in your control
  >   you need to run it in some sort  of
  >   host. VS2005 provides a new control
  >   host for this purpose but I find  that
  >   even this is not sufficient sometimes.